# PHP Errors When Upgrading Freeform & Tag From v3 to v4

Tags: solspace-freeform, upgrade, php-errors, solspace-tag

When trying to upgrade Solspace Freeform and Solspace Tag, I'm getting PHP errors.

For Freeform, I'm trying to update from 3.1.0 to 4.0.12. When I go to the Freeform module page, I get this PHP error:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1146
>
> Table 'db_production.exp_freeform_multipage_hashes' doesn't exist
>
> TRUNCATE `exp_freeform_multipage_hashes`
>
> Filename: third_party/freeform/upd.freeform.php
>
> Line Number: 472

For Tag, I'm trying to update from 3.0.5 to 4.2.3, and I'm getting these errors when I try to access the module:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:
>   file_get_contents(/path/to/my/system/expressionengine/third_party/tag/tag.sql) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory
>
> Filename: tag/upd.tag.php
>
> Line Number: 817
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /path/to/my/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 412
>
> A Database Error Occurred The query you submitted is not valid.
>
> Filename: third_party/tag/upd.tag.php
>
> Line Number: 828

I've already tried completely re-uploading the files from scratch, making sure that the old files are gone from the system, but I still get these errors.

EE 2.6.1

Comment: Did you manage to get this fixed? I am having the same Freeform issue. Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer, because it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

When updating freeform, you need to delete the old directories before uploading the new:

Updating:

```
Within your sites ./system/expressionengine/third_party/ directory, delete the freeform folder and upload the new one from the /system/expressionengine/third_party/ directory in your download package.
Within your sites ./themes/third_party/ directory, delete the freeform folder and upload the new one from the /themes/third_party/ directory in your download package.
Go to the Modules area in the ExpressionEngine control panel and click the Run Module Updates button.
Upgrading from Freeform 3.x (if applicable):
    Go to the Utilities tab in the Freeform control panel, and run the Migration utility.
    Review the Freeform 3.x to 4.x Upgrade Guide and update your templates as necessary.
```

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/install_update/